# OS Development in C++ Questions

Tags: operating-systems

As a Master's project, I am designing a simple operating system.  It is being designed to run in 16-bit Real Mode on an x86 architecture.  Ideally, I would like to develop this OS in C++, and only using assembly where necessary.  Thus far, I have a boot loader written in assembly, that loads a kernel that is a mix of C++ and asm.  My question is in regards to using C++.  As of now, it has compiled and can run, but I have not used any dynamic memory allocation.

If I were using C, it would make sense to write malloc functions that would handle memory allocation, but in C++ the new keyword is used.  So...

**How does 'new' work behind the scenes to allocate memory, and how would I go about handling this?**

And as a corollary...

**Does it make sense to try to use C++ to take advantage of its higher level abstactions?  Or would it be more of a headache to use it and should I stick with C?**

Please provide rationale if you believe that C++ would not be a good choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `new` keyword hands off the actual allocation to `operator new`, which behaves rather similar to `malloc`: it gets memory from somewhere. The compiler will then do all the constructor magic. Therefore, the C++ compiler will expect the C++ runtime lib (or your code) to provide an implementation of `operator new`.

It certainly makes sense to use C++ for certain abstractions. There's no reason why an OS should roll its own `std::list<>`. Exceptions are far more troublesome. In between there's a gradient from useful to useless stuff. `std::complex` ?  It works perfectly, but why would you need it?

Answer (score 5):

Many of the advantages of C++ over C have nothing to do with runtime support, and in those cases there's really no difference between code written in C and code written in C++.  Templates, for example, don't do anything at runtime.  They do nothing you couldn't do with a lot of extra typing.  C++ is a very reasonable language to write operating systems in, since it provides low-level access when you need it, combined with higher-level abstractions than C when you don't need to focus on the bit-twiddling.

`new` does two things:  it gets memory from somewhere, and it runs any necessary constructors.  In getting the memory, it's no different from `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be reasonable to give a rough idea of the code that's normally generated for a `new` expression. It's generated by the compiler, but *if* you were implementing it as a function, it would look something like this:

```
template <class T>
T *new_object() { 
    void *raw_data = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
    return new(raw_data) T;
}
```

If you care about how `new` works, the (nearly) inevitable follow-up is how `delete` works:

```
template <class T>
void delete_object(T const *object) { 
    object->~T();
    ::operator delete(object);
}
```

As others have already pointed out, `::operator new` and `::operator delete` are pretty basic memory allocators. For example, on a Unix-like system they'd probably call something like `brk` or `sbrk` to allocate large chunks of memory, and then hand out smaller chunks from those big blocks. In your own OS, you still probably want some sort of analog to `sbrk` and such -- something that starts with essentially all memory as "free", and allocates pieces of memory as needed. Given that you're working in real mode, that'll probably be *fairly* simple -- given the small amount of memory available, a practical design nearly needs to emphasize small size over elaborate algorithms.

Answer (score -3):

Most operating systems are written in C I think. On the other hand it's a master's project so do something different and interesting.

Comment: Most large operating systems were initially written before C++ was available. That limited the choice. :-)

Comment: sometimes I think downvotes are contagious.